# Trigo Equation : $\sin3x +\sin^3x =\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Problem :

Trigo Equation : $\sin3x +\sin^3x =\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin2x$

My approach : If I make  it $3\sin x -4\sin^3x$ it is becoming too lengthy... please help if other approach is available..

(I got this problem at http://www.mathstudy.in .... If any student want some practice papers for JEE Main he can download the same from this website....thanks..)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Using $\displaystyle \sin3A,\sin2A$ formula, we have

$$\sin x \left(3-4\sin^2x+\sin^2x-\frac{\sqrt3}4\cdot2\cos x\right)=0$$

Use $\displaystyle\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\cos x$

and keep in mind that $-1\le\cos x\le1$ for real $x$